# TypeORM migrations no changes were found

Tags: node.js, migration, typeorm

I'm trying to generate migrations with TypeOrm. When I change an entity, it should detect this change and generate a new migration.

I get the following error message:

> No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command

Why am I getting this error message when I changed something in my entities files?

I'm using this command to run TypeOrm:

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/typeormConfig.ts",
```

This is my typeormConfig.ts file:

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
import * as path from "path";
import * as dotEnv from 'dotenv'

console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'entity/**.entity.ts'))

const result = dotEnv.config({ path: './ormconfig.env' });

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  port: +process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  //synchronize: true,
  synchronize: false,
  // migrationsRun: false,
  entities: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'entity/**.entity.*')],
  migrations: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'migration/**')],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: "src/entity",
    migrationsDir: "src/migration"
  }
}

export default config;
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `export default config` by `export = config`?

Answer (score 0):

Update the entities & migrations directory link like this

```
entities: [__dirname + '/entity/**/*.entity.ts', __dirname + '/entity/**/*.entity.js'],
migrations: [__dirname + '/migration/**/*.ts', __dirname + '/migration/**/*.js'],
```

It works for me & should work.

Answer (score -1):

0. Make sure you configured:

```json
  "migrations": ["db-migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "db-migrations"
  }
```

1. Enable `synchronize` and go to the prev. state of your schema (run the project - this will reset DB changes)
2. Make the code changes (apply them from git or move to the changed branch)
3. Disable `synchronize` and run the project (to make it compile the changes) - it may fail running but it is ok
4. run `typeorm migration:generate -n TestMigration` and it will succeed

From there on leave `synchronize` disabled, just compile the project before running `migration:generate`